# setuptools ez_setup return me UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-xp, setuptools

I'm using python 3.3 and Windows XP(32x).
I tried to install setuptools.
I write in command line:

```
py ez_setup.py install
```

And it return me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    exec(init_file.read(), command_ns)
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\docume~1\jakov\locals~1\temp\tmpymerwg\setuptools-3.5.1\setuptools\_
init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "c:\docume~1\jakov\locals~1\temp\tmpymerwg\setuptools-3.5.1\setuptools\e
tension.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "c:\docume~1\jakov\locals~1\temp\tmpymerwg\setuptools-3.5.1\setuptools\d
st.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.compat import numeric_types, basestring
  File "c:\docume~1\jakov\locals~1\temp\tmpymerwg\setuptools-3.5.1\setuptools\c
mpat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208, in SimpleHTTPRequestHan
ler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 6: ordinal
not in range(128)
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

I am also using python 2.7, but I want to install setuptools for python 3.3.

Comment: Use `py -3 ez_setup.py`. By the way, pip and setuptools are included with 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open my file with IDE and run it(because if you run code from cmd and you have both python2 and python3 it will run with python2 and iif you run it from IDE for python3 it will run in python3).

I really don't know if my explanation is true(because I don't have python2 on path), but I know that some files only work when you run it with IDE, and some only with cmd(or graphical).